# Select slide with condition in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have two PowerPoint slide ie slides(1) & slides(2).
Want to change slides(i) to slides(1) when j<5 & change slides(i) to slides(2) when j>0. But I cannot configure.

```
Dim i As integer

sz = GetObject("C:\Users\Desktop\sample.xlsx").sheets(1).Range("D2:D9")
For j = 1 To UBound(sz)
If j<5 Then i = 1 Else i = 2
strPic = "rectangle" & j
Set shp = Application.Presentations(1).Slides(i).Shapes(strPic)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your objective. Please explain in more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: Want to change slides(i) to slides(1) when j<5 & change slides(i) to slides(2) when j>0. So what logic to be implemented to get above result.

Comment: Repeating the same opaque formula does not clarify your goal. Are you trying to reorder the slides? Please use words.

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanted to re-order the slides, use the following syntax. You can re-configure the conditional statements.

*Also, please format your question properly, and please be more specific. When @John Korchok requested for more details, you just copy-pasted the question and did not elucidate on your case. Please avoid incoherent questions.*

```
If j<5 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo (2)
ElseIf j>0 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo (2)
End If
```